# Check if a variable has "moved"

Tags: java, android

I have a thread wherein the program constantly gets the user's distance from another phone thru bluetooth.

I opted to implement a text-to-speech feature wherein the program will "talk" when the user moves a meter closer/farther. I am already able to get the distance but the problem is I have no idea how to check if the distance has moved atleast 1 meter closer/farther. For example:

```
Initial distance: 0.81 meters
```

The TTS feature should activate when the value increases/decreases by roughly 1 meter.

```
Should activate TTS when distance becomes: 1.81, 2.85, 3.90
```

Notice that the 2nd value `2.85` is not exactly 1 meter farther from the last distance `1.81` because the distance being obtained "jumps" meaning if you display the distance and start walking away it will look similar to this:

```
Distance: 1.01, 1.86, 2.31, 3.29, ...
```

I have tried various ways but I just can't seem to do it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need to calculate the difference in distances *since you last activated TTS*.  The calculation is simply a subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
int initDist = x;
int newDist = y;

int diff = newDist - initDist;

if(diff >= 1){
    // activate TTS here;
    initDist = newDist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
int initialDistance = x;//declare it global
int newDistance = y;

if(Math.abs(newDistance -initialDistance )>=1) {
//TTS;
initialDistance = newDistance;
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. m so used to of creating own functions that I forget these libraries exist :D :P